# CSS Responsive Fluid Square (with scrollable content)

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

So I'm trying to build a pure CSS responsive square (well actually I'm trying to build a circle but that's easy once I've got the square.)

In other words:

- I want a `div` that has a `height` that is a percentage of the `body` and a `width` that is equal to that (or vice versa).
- The `div` also needs to have another `div` inside it which can contain content and `overflow: auto`.
- Lastly, the `div` can never exceed the `height` (or `width`) of the `body` or `viewport`.

So far, I have got some solutions working partially (i.e. in `portrait` but not `landscape`) using a 1px transparent .gif as an `img` to fill out a wrapper `div`. Not ideal semantics but I don't see how this can be done without it.

```
<div class="wrap">
<img src="http://www.neurillion.com/p/35/static/media/images/1x1t.gif" />
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Title</h2>              
            <p> Lorem... etc. </p> 
         </div> 
     </main>
</div>
```

Here are my CSS solutions and what is wrong with them:

1. This works except it exceeds the `height` of the `body` in `landscape` (`max-height` in any of the elements does not solve this):

   ```
   .wrap {
     background: blue;
     margin: 10% auto;
     width: 70%;
     position:relative;
     text-align:center;
   }
   .wrap img {
     border: 1px solid black;
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
   }
   main {
     background: red;
     display: block;
     border-radius:50%;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top:0
   }

   main div {
     background: green;
     overflow: auto;
     display:inline-block;
     height:70%;
     width: 70%;
     margin-top:15%;  
   }
   ```

   [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/qdIwt)
2. Next I added a `landscape` media query to swap around the `height` and `width` values. Same problem.
       `@media(orientation:landscape) {
         .wrap {
           margin: auto 10%;
           height: 70%;
           width: auto;
         }
       }`

   [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/zAvtl)
3. At this point I started looking into `.wrap`'s parent elements , namely the `body` and `html`. ([Resource on the difference between them.](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)) I added `height` and `max-height: 100%` to both of them, but no joy. I've also tried adding another `div` container as I thought it might be easier to control the height, but that doesn't seem to be doing much either.

And now I'm pretty much out of options. I'm fairly sure the solution is something to do with the `html` and `body` elements and the way they are so eager to expand vertically but I'm not really sure how else to stop them doing so.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `vw`, `vh` and `vmin` to scale the square:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r9VQs/

CSS (changed part only):

```
.wrap {
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90vh;
    max-height: 90vh;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You can also use `vmin` (which gives better results but is less well supported) and forego the image:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r9VQs/2/

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90vmin;
    height: 90vmin;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

`vh`, `vw` and `vmin` are units equivalent to 1% of their respective viewport dimensions (`vh` is viewport-height, `vw` is viewport-width and `vmin` is whichever has a smaller value).

Please see http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units for browser support.

Comment: You sir, are a hero. Thanks very much. Especially for the caniuse link as well.

Comment: Out of interest, unrelated- Why do you prefer to use jsfiddle to codepen?

Comment: I use codepen all the time actually, but it's a little bit too "heavy" for demo's. I'm [AMKohn](http://codepen.io/AMKohn) over there if you're interested.